# PHPExcel adding html to xls

Tags: php, phpexcel

I have a page that creates an xls file with PHPExcel on post, which works fine, the file download pops up and everything is golden, but when i try to open the file i get an error saying excel cannot open the file. I checked all the data going in and everything was fine, so i figured it had to be something with the file.

I opened the downloaded xls in notepad++, and sure enough, there was html at the top of the file, the same html for the page, up to where the content was called and the php checking the post ran. As soon as i deleted that it opened up just fine, still missing a few fields, but I'd like to make it actually viewable before i worry about that.

Here's my code for creating the xls

```
global $__CMS_CONN__;
error_reporting(E_ALL);
$listmem = $_SESSION['listmem'];
$evtdate1 = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-1 year', strtotime(date('Y-m-d'))));
$evtdate2 = date('Y-m-d');
require_once('/web/content/wolf/plugins/Classes/PHPExcel.php');
$sql = "SELECT Count(*) AS number FROM (SELECT DISTINCT event_timestamp FROM membership_attendance_log WHERE event_timestamp >= '".$evtdate1."' AND event_timestamp <= '".$evtdate2."') as numevents";
$evtcount = $__CMS_CONN__->prepare($sql);
$evtcount->execute();
$count = $evtcount->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells('A1:C1');
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
            ->setCellValue('A1', 'Date Range: '.$evtdate1." to ".$evtdate2)
            ->setCellValue('D1', 'Total number of events: '.$count['number'])
            ->setCellValue('A2', 'Member')
            ->setCellValue('B2', 'Missed Meetings')
            ->setCellValue('C2', 'Attendance')
            ->setCellValue('D2', 'Business Name')
            ->setCellValue('E2', 'Title')
            ->setCellValue('F2', 'Phone')
            ->setCellValue('G2', 'Email');
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A1:H1')->getFont()->setBold(true);
$i = 3;
foreach($listmem as $row)
{
    $qry = "SELECT Count(membership_individual_id) AS attendance FROM membership_attendance_log WHERE membership_individual_id=".$row['id']." AND event_timestamp >= '".$evtdate1."' AND event_timestamp <= '".$evtdate2."'";
    $stmt = $__CMS_CONN__->prepare($qry);
    $stmt->execute();
    $attendance = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
                ->setCellValue('A'.$i, $row['first_name']." ".$row['last_name'])
                ->setCellValue('B'.$i, $attendance['attendance'])
                ->setCellValue('C'.$i, floor($attendance['attendance'] / $count['number']))
                ->setCellValue('D'.$i, $row['business_name'])
                ->setCellValue('E'.$i, $row['title'])
                ->setCellValue('F'.$i, $row['business_phone'])
                ->setCellValue('G'.$i, $row['email']);
    $i++;
}
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('A')->setAutoSize(true);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('B')->setAutoSize(true);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('C')->setAutoSize(true);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('D')->setAutoSize(true);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('E')->setAutoSize(true);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('F')->setAutoSize(true);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('G')->setAutoSize(true);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('H')->setAutoSize(true);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setTitle('Report');
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="Report-'.date("mdY").'.xlsx"');
header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');
$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');
$objWriter->save('php://output');
exit;
```

This is on a site using wolfCMS, just fyi. I tried pulling it out of the file and just having it post to a seperate php file but i still got the same thing.

Comment: This is goign to be specific yo how the CMS is implemented... the code youve given doesnt really have a lot to do with it. you need to find a way to turn off the CMS output completely when youre handling a post to the URL that runs this code. This may be as simple as making another layout and/or template that is completely empty and using that...

Comment: It isn't PHPExcel that's adding the html to the file, it must be something to do with the way your CMS sends its own output, with the HTML being warapped around the PHPExcel output. PHPExcel simply saves the xls to the php://output stream, without any knowledge of what might have been sent previously by your CMS

Comment: I had thought about that, but then why did I get the same thing when it was posting to a separate file?

Comment: @Ryan - I've no idea how wolfCMS works... have you created new headers and footers for this page? or set the current headers/footers to hidden?

Comment: Yeah. I created a new page with the code to create the xls with no header or layout and it works great. I just don't understand how it was getting the html from the layout when i had it running from a separate php file.

Comment: If you're running from within a framework or CMS, then generally it's that which runs your PHP file, so any output or headings generated by that are wrapped around the output from your script

Comment: Yeah (@mark), take a look at the `.htaccess` its likeley redirecting all requests to index.php for processing...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding this just before sending the header
`ob_end_clean();`
It should solve your problem. I think some data on output buffer is causing the issue.